# SVN Externals unexpected state issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was trying out `SVN External`, what I want to do is have an external folder and copy over libraries from there into my Lib Folder.

I went to SVN Externals, and there added the lib folder and path to svn
I checked out my Project and I got the below error 
[image: My Svn Checkout]

Comment: What does the definition of your `svn:externals` for the `lib` folder look like?

Comment: Path: lib
URL: svn://mysvn/trunk/External/log4net
And my lib is committed to the svn. Thats correct?

Comment: It should be something like: `svn://mysvn/trunk/External/log4net log4net`, following the `URL WC_FOLDER` convention. Out of interest, try using TortoiseSVN's Repository Browser to browse to `svn://mysvn/trunk/External/log4net`, and also try to check it out to somewhere temporarily.

Comment: no what i want is copy the libraries from the External\log4net to Project\Lib folder So something like External\log4net\dll to Libs\dll

Comment: Set your `lib` external to `svn://mysvn/trunk/External/log4net dll` so that the contents of that URL would be placed in `lib\dll` in your checkout.

Comment: three thoughts:  1. don't check binaries into source control.  2. don't use svn:externals as a poor mans dependency management solution.  3. read about nuget.   I know it's impossible to not sound trite - but this path is going to make you (or your successors) sad.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience some scenarios will leave folders or files included by use of `svn:externals` in state `the item has a Switched URL relative to the parent`.
This is most likely reason for your problem. You should be able to spot such elements using `svn status` command, status "S", or [TortoiseSVN `Check For Modifications`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn26h.png), status `normal (s)`.

Simplest way to resolve this is selecting action `Switch back to parent` from item's context menu in TortoiseSVN `Check For Modifications` window. This action may result in deletion of file or folder from working copy, subsequent update will fetch new copy from repository.