# Tortoise SVN Error after update: 'The specified path has an unexpected status'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

My tortoise SVN has one issue related with the externals file that I'm unable to identify, this is happening during the checkout process.

After do "commit" and download one fresh checkout this path has this unexpected status.

**Exernal Failed:** C:\Archive\test4\src\STM\SDK_A18_C052
Error: The specified path has an unexpected status

Please verify my external related to this path:

url: ^/Platform/Integration/ST_40/trunk/src/STM/SDK_A18_C052
local path: src/STM/SDK_A18_C052

1- I tried to create the externals again.

2- I tried to delete this directory and create it again.

3- I tried to realocate this file.

4- I tried to redo the checkout.

Best Regards,
Mr. Desperate Man

Answer (score 19):

How I fixed this problem:

1. Remove external from `svn:externals`
2. Make SVN update
3. Add external back to `svn:externals`
4. Make SVN update

Comment: renaming svn:external name is sufficient

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Simple, and can be done on the command-line.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with an **external file** and was unwilling to make a commit (as [suggested by Shadow76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130428/tortoise-svn-error-after-update-the-specified-path-has-an-unexpected-status/30261428#30261428))

In [this bug report](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4002) I found the following procedure **without a commit**:

1. change the **local name** of the external (file or folder)
2. make an SVN **Update**
3. change the **local name** of the external **back** to before step 1
4. make another SVN **Update**

which resulted in a successful external.

Comment: It might have been enough to delete the local (external) file and update from the repository

Comment: Your answer worked, during some years we never had this issue in the past, but now isn't working, probably it was a conflict generated by some reason in the next attempt I'll delete the files at the project and commit again.

Comment: This worked! To make it clearer: In your working copy open the SVN properties of the folder, edit externals and change the local name of the external in question here. Then do the update. After that you can revert the props and update again.

Comment: @VictorHD: If my answer worked, would you accept my answer? See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/300359

Answer (score 6):

Inspired from the post above I have used another step (step 3) where you don't need to create the external again but do revert. After the change the steps look like:

1. Remove external from `svn:externals`
2. Make SVN update
3. Revert
4. Make SVN update

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove external
2. Commit
3. Remove folder for external
4. Commit
5. Add external again
6. SVN Update

Comment: I tried your tip without success the file still is with unexpected status.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue recently.  It turned out my external conflicted with an existing folder in my repository.

You can use repo-browser to look for a conflicting folder in your repository.  If you find a folder that matches the local path of your external, you'll have to delete or rename the offending folder in your repository, or use a different local path for your external.

Answer (score 1):

For me there was no need to rename or commit anything.

I found useful information [here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651969/svn-externals-unexpected-state-issue)
and after reading it, I just tried `switch` command and kept the path (so I did not actually switch), which caused the faulty external file to be deleted and re-added.

Problem solved in 1 step.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to solve this problem without commit or add externals:

1. Remove `external file` from `svn - properties - externals`
2. Remove `external file` itself
3. Run `svn update .`
4. Run `svn revert .` //revert root directory
5. Run `svn update .`